# matplotlib TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got an error with the code below. This plot works well in Python2, but in Python3 i've got TypeError. Have no idea, how to fix it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DF = pd.DataFrame({
    'day':     [datetime(2018,1,1).date()+timedelta(x+1) for x in range(100)],
    'balance': np.random.normal(100,100,100)
})
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(DF['day'], DF['balance'], color='lightblue')
plt.xlabel('day', fontsize=20)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.show()
```

Error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10
>         6 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>   ----> 7 ax.bar(DF['day'], DF['balance'], color='lightblue')
>         8 plt.xlabel('day', fontsize=20)
>         9 myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
>
> /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py in
>   inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1896
>   warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.**name**),    1897
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   -> 1898             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1899         pre_doc = inner.**doc**    1900         if pre_doc is None:
>
> /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py
>   in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)    2103         if
>   align == 'center':    2104             if orientation == 'vertical':
>   -> 2105                 left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]    2106             elif orientation ==
>   'horizontal':    2107                 bottom = [bottom[i] - height[i]
>   / 2.
>
> /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py
>   in (.0)    2103         if align == 'center':    2104
>   if orientation == 'vertical':
>   -> 2105                 left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]    2106             elif orientation ==
>   'horizontal':    2107                 bottom = [bottom[i] - height[i]
>   / 2.
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and
>   'float'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date2num` on the date column

**Ex:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num       #-->Update
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DF = pd.DataFrame({
    'day':     [datetime(2018,1,1).date()+timedelta(x+1) for x in range(100)],
    'balance': np.random.normal(100,100,100)
})
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
DF['day'] = DF['day'].apply(date2num)      #-->Update

ax.bar(DF['day'], DF['balance'], color='lightblue')
plt.xlabel('day', fontsize=20)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you are not using time delta, you might see an error like this, `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'`solution is to use `index.to_series().apply(date2num)`